# How to get all MAC addresses connected to WiFi with node.js?

Tags: node.js, wifi, mac-address

Is there a way to list all connected devices' MAC address using node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try this node module which works like nmap.

https://github.com/jas-/node-libnmap

```
var nmap = require('libnmap');

nmap.discover(function(err, report) {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);

  for (var item in report) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(report[item]));
  }
});
```

This library has some good utility tools for similar things what you are looking for.

Here are 2 other modules that do something similar as well.

https://github.com/TheThingSystem/node-arp-a

https://github.com/goliatone/arpscan

Comment: Thanks much! This is incredibly useful. I'll definitely try these out! Here, take 10 free good vibe units for you!

Comment: Great. Hope this was helpful. Please approve the answer so that others get benefitted as well.

Comment: Done! Sorry it took so long.